Reinstalling anaconda navigator with no module named conda
My anaconda navigator is 2.6.3 previously. Yesterday, I reinstalled it with BCUninstall with a very clean uninstalling. Then I deleted .conda folders in my Users/ folder.
After reinstalling under "just me", the navigator cannot be opened. Then when I clicked Anaconda Powershell or prompt, the info showed below:
from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
After that, I added PATH and uninstalled the Python 12 in my local windows 11. But the trouble is still there.
Then I installed under "All users". Navigator can be launched. But when I install some packages like seaborn, "Multi errors" comes up in Navigator.
Can someone tell me what is the problem? If I could, I still want to install it under "just me". Thanks
